# Power arduino with 7.2v rc racing battery?

Tags: arduino, voltage, batteries, current

I just want to make sure before I destroy my arduino.. Is it okay if I power my Arduino Mega from a high current 7.2v battery pack? 
The battery I'm planning to use is this :

http://www.ebay.com/itm/7-4-V-30C-5200mAH-2S-Lipo-Li-Po-Lipoly-Battery-for-RC-Car-Boat-/261351067166?pt=Radio_Control_Parts_Accessories&hash=item3cd9bcce1e

The voltage is within the recommended 7-9V and it's a 5.2A pack, and the arduino will only draw as much current as it needs, so I don't need to worry about current, do I?

Note: I will be connecting GPS/GSM module, and some other sensors.
I won't use any motors for cars or boats.
I need this because I want the arduino to live as long as possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be OK but be aware that the voltage regulator device on the arduino may not regulate when the battery voltage drops below 7V because, from memory it is a 7805 device and it, for proper operation needs a minimum of 7V to ensure the output remains regulated.

Comment: You are right about 7805 but I guess it depends on the specific implementation, not all board use it. For example I checked a couple of Arduino UNO and they were using [MC33269](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC33269-D.PDF) and [LM1117](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm1117-n), both low dropout regulators that only require about 1.2v higher input. In any case the OP should check the requirements of the regulator used in his specific board.

Comment: Thanks Andy and @alexan_e
Any suggestions to solve the voltage drop issue? 
Other than using a higher voltage battery.

Comment: @AdelBibi you could use a boost voltage converter to guarantee (say) 7V5 output even if the battery dropped to maybe 6V. The alternative is to swap out the 7805 on the arduino board with a low-drop-out regulator.

Comment: @AdelBibi A boost converter that will be converted back to 5v will lower the efficiency, I think a low dropout regulator like [LM2940-5](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm2940-n) with a typical voltage drop of 0.5v at 1A (1v max) and much lower at lower currents (typical 0.11v at 100mA) would suite your application.